# Oracle Forms If List of Values Contain No Entries Show Message

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I have a button and this code in WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger of button. When I press button, show a LOV. And LOV's query gets result depends on user who press button. I want to show specific message like 'You have no authorization' if list of value gets no entries. But I get error message  "FRM-41830: List of Values contains no entries". What can I do?

```
DECLARE
   A   BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
   A := SHOW_LOV ('LIST_OF_VALUE');

   SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY (...);

   GO_BLOCK ('...');

   EXECUTE_QUERY ();

   :SYSTEM.message_level := 25;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      MESSAGE ('You have no authorization');
      :SYSTEM.message_level := 0;
END;
```

Comment: give more information. what is SHOW_LOV

Answer (score 0):

there is no relation with lov and exception . Please check the lov query and try to get the count if count is greater than 0 then show lov if not display message.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your code that would raise a NO_DATA_FOUND exception. However, if the record group underlying the LOV called by SHOW_LOV contains 0 records, the BOOLEAN return value for SHOW_LOV will be FALSE.  You can try to trap that, or possibly put an ON-ERROR trigger on the button to trap the "FRM-41830: List of Values contains no entries" error and return your customized message there.